# File deletion fails sometimes on Mac

Tags: macos, delete-file, unlink, file-manager

[Technical Q&A 1497](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1497.html)
 and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246751/race-condition-when-calling-fsdeleteobject) (whose answer copied from the tech note) indicate that, when getting `fBsyErr` from `FSDeleteObject`, the proper workaround is to call `FSUnlinkObject` on 10.5+.

What is the technical difference between the two APIs `FSDeleteObject` and `FSUnlinkObject`
(other than noting that `FSUnlinkObject` does not appear in the documentation)?  Why should `unlink` be the fallback and not the primary API?

Comment: "API functions"**. An API is a set of functions, not a single function ;) I'm a terminology Nazi. /ontopic - interesting question. My thought would be that deleting it will delete it permanently, whereas unlink simply takes it off of the list (so to speak), but the file is still there. I might be wrong, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that `FSDeleteObject` came first because it continues a line of file-deletion functions that existed long before the Mac OS merged with Unix, whereas unlinking a file is a Unix concept.

Comment: Does that suggest a reason why Delete should be the preferred call? If so, I'm missing it.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple document you linked explains the difference quite clearly. FSUnlinkObject has the same semantics as unlink() - deleting open files is allowed. FSDeleteObject does not allow deleting open files and returns that error code when you attempt to do so.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain anything -- why should delete be the primary and unlink the fallback if busy?  Why not use unlink all the time?

Comment: @Richard: Who says delete is the primary? The Q&A linked above says "This API call is the preferred solution to avoid an error when deleting a file on 10.5 and later."  But that suggests one reason not to use unlink all the time: one might be trying to write code compatible with OS 10.4.  That was probably a bigger issue when the Q&A was written than it is now.